# Using ST_* functions with different origin results in: Function not found

Tags: postgis

I've built a query which uses ST_asGeoJSON(); and If I run it on my server through pgadmin with credentials of UserX it runs like a charm.

But when connecting through an webapp with other credentialsof UserY it returns me the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function st_asgeojson(public.geometry) does not exist
>   LINE 17: ,ST_AsGeoJSON(vbo.geopunt) AS vbo_geopunt
>   ^
>   HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

So I tried to explicitly cast to `::point` but then It still does not work.

If I connect my webapp with the working credentials of UserX it also produces the same error.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: try putting the schema name in front:  public.ST_asGeoJSON()

Comment: Does not work, still a function not found error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24204589/error-using-st-asgeojson-with-postgis

Comment: That `select * from pg_proc where proname = 'st_asgeojson'` returns only 5 functions. :(

Comment: try this post for permissions:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31244/postgis-qgis-and-granting-permissions